# postgresql/sql - join(Double?) two tables and sort by a column of the second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `assignment` and `message`.

`assignment`

| id | message | assignor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 33 | 909 |
| 32 | 13 | 5464 |
| 52 | 521 | 909 |

`message`

| id | text | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | Merheba | NEW |
| 43 | Salam | READ |
| 312 | Olá | READ |
| 521 | hello | NEW |
| 412 | Hola | NEW |
| 212 | Hallo | READ |
| 765 | Saluton | READ |

`assignment` refers to `message`.

I want to query all messages where their `state` is 'NEW' and their `assignor` is 909 in `assignment` or they do not exist in `assignment`. And I need to sort the list by `assignor`.

I have used this query to fetch all the messages but I am not sure if is possible to sort the result.

```
select *
from message
where (
  id not in (
    select message
    from assignment
  )
  or id in (
    select message
    from assignment
    where assignee = 909
  )
)
and state = 'NEW';
```

Is it possible to simplify the query? I look for the  message two times.

The result must be:

| id | text | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | Merhaba | NEW |
| 521 | hello | NEW |
| 412 | Hola | NEW |

The first two rows have `assignor` (909 in `assignment`), and all of the three rows are 'NEW'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.  I am inclined to write such logic using `exists`:

```
select m.*
from message m
where m.state = 'NEW' and
      (exists (select 1 from assignment a where a.message = m.id and a.assignee = 909) or
       not exists (select 1 from assignment where a.message = m.id)
      );
```

If messages do not have multiple `assignee`s, then you can change this to:

```
select m.*
from message m
where m.state = 'NEW' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from assignment a
                  where a.message = m.id and a.assignee <> 909
                 );
```

EDIT:

In order to sort by `assignor`, you need to `join` that table in:

```
select m.*
from message m left join
     assignment a
     on m.id = a.message
where m.state = 'NEW' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from assignment a
                  where a.message = m.id and a.assignee <> 909
                 )
order by a.assignor;
```

And similarly for the second version.

You can also make the whole thing a `join`:

```
select m.*
from message m left join
     assignment a
     on m.id = a.message
where m.state = 'NEW' and
      (a.message is null or  -- no matches
       a.assignee = 909
      )
order by a.assignor;
```

Comment: Thanks. Messages have unique assignee. I liked the solution, but it does not sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE assignment(
  id INT,
  message INT,
  assignor INT
);
CREATE TABLE message(
  id INT,
  text VARCHAR(255),
  state VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Your test data:

```
INSERT INTO assignment (id, message, assignor) VALUES
  (11, 33, 909),
  (32, 13, 5464),
  (52, 521, 909);
INSERT INTO message (id, text, state) VALUES
  (33, 'Merheba', 'NEW'),
  (43, 'Salam', 'READ'),
  (312, 'Olá', 'READ'),
  (521, 'hello', 'NEW'),
  (412, 'Hola', 'NEW'),
  (212, 'Hallo', 'READ'),
  (765, 'Saluton', 'READ');
```

Your requirements:

> I want to query all messages where their `state` is 'NEW' and their `assignor` is 909 in `assignment` or they do not exist in `assignment`. And I need to sort the list by `assignor`.

The query you need:

```
SELECT message.*
FROM message
LEFT JOIN assignment
  ON message.id = assignment.message
WHERE message.state = 'NEW'
  AND (
    assignment.assignor = 909
    OR assignment.assignor IS NULL
  )
ORDER BY assignment.assignor;
```

Its result:

| id | text | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | Merheba | NEW |
| 521 | hello | NEW |
| 412 | Hola | NEW |